# Fixing HTML textbox value permanently

Tags: javascript, html

[image]I am working on GPS project where i am trying to take altitude(sea level) value in textbox1 and trying to convert it into ground level value in textbox2.

Here GPS Altitude(ASL) value is dynamic for example..

```
Altitude reading (ASL) =  250.00 Mtr (initial value) textbox1
Altitude reading (ASL) =  300.00 Mtr (value increases to 50) textbox1
Altitude reading (ASL) =  400.00 Mtr (current value increases to 100) textbox1

Altitude reading (AGL) =  ASL(current value) - ASL(initial value)
Altitude reading (AGL) = 150 Mtrs. textbox2
```

As i said Altitude reading (ASL) is dynamic if i use 3rd textbox for example textbox3 to store initial value then how can i lock the value so that it should not get changed after getting it from textbox 1. Any possibility with HTML or java script ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: mark it readonly ?

Comment: textbox with readonly attribute takes redirected values if input being done from other textbox

Comment: Only if you keep calling the function that copies the value

Comment: "input being done from other textbox" this I don't get... can u explain ?

Comment: A textbox from which GPS value(Altitude) is getting updated to textbox1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to copy the value of the `input`, then delete the `input` from the document and place the value into a non-editable element that takes the place of the `input`.

```js
var input1 = document.getElementById("txt1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("txt2");
var output = document.getElementById("output")
var container = document.getElementById("container");

input1.addEventListener("change", disable);
input2.addEventListener("input", sum);

function disable(evt){
  var val = input1.value;      // Get the value of the input
  container.innerHTML = "";    // Remove input from container
  container.textContent = val; // Place value in non-editible container
}

function sum(){
  output.textContent = +input1.value + +input2.value;
};

sum();
```

```css
#output {
  display:inline-block;
  width:5em;
  padding:2px;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  border:1px solid #222;
}
```

```html
Value 1: <span id="container"><input id="txt1"></span><br>
Value 2: <input id="txt2">
Sum: <span id="output"></span>

<div>(Change the value in the first input and then leave that field.)</div>
```

Comment: I apologies if i fail to make you understand but i don't want value of first textbox to be changed once it get value..... only one time value insertion should be allowed so that i can subtract value2 with value one . this will be my Above ground level value from GPS.. attributes like Disable,Readonly doesn't work if value 1 is getting value from other textboxes as it overwrite values ....anyways thank you for your kind reply !

Comment: @DavidMathias Oh, ok. Give me a couple of moments to update my answer. There is an easy solution.

Comment: @DavidMathias See my updated answer for your solution.

Comment: Great answer of the century .. Thank you so much Scott.This is what i was looking for...... I will work hard on my programming skills

Comment: @DavidMathias You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote and mark as "the" answer. Good luck!

Comment: i want to "voteup" but i have 14 reputation and system require 15 reputation.. can you please Vote up my question may be i get some reputation. thank you !

Comment: @DavidMathias LOL. Done! +1